# laravel подключаю имеющуюся базу

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Подключаю имеющуюся базу к ларавель. Но таблицу user ларавель не находит, ищет users. iduser - yt не хочет, хочет видеть только id.
Что сделать чтоб не надо было к таблицам добавлять "s" , и во всех таблицах было "id"?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#table-names

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. Теперь возникает делема - создавать базу по конвенции - имя таблицы - существительное в единственном числе или подстраиваться под laravel - писать во множественном? почему вообще в ларавел таблицы во множественном числе?

Comment: у вас наименования в принципе не правильные. Так да же просто человеку читать неудобно. 1. Почему во множественном числе: у вас таблица users( Пользователи), а не таблица user (Пользователь), у вас там много пользователей соответственно название во множественном числе.. Как и news, articles, templates, settings и так далее.  Так как мы храним там много записей данного типа. 2. iduser - это вообще кошмар так писать. Название полей в бд должны быть в shake_case. А то скажите с первого раза что я за поле написал: newstitlefromapi.

Comment: Все primary ключи по умолчанию id в ларавель. Все внешние ключи формируются так user_id, news_is, article_id. Название связующих таблиц идёт так же через shake_case плюс расположение первых букв в названиях таблиц по алфавиту: article_user, profile_user, user_rating.

Comment: Если надо изменить primary у таблицы при получении записи через модель, то укажите в модели свойство protected $primaryKey = 'iduser';

Comment: По конвенции таблицы в базе данных называются именами существительными в единственном числе. Отсюда у меня и возник вопрос.

Comment: iduser - это я опечатался. Конечно - id_user  или user_id